# Play 2.3 got incompatible errors for DefaultReads

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.3

I am trying to update play to 2.3 from 2.2, but I got several errors complaining about DefaultReads incompatible.

```
[error] Could not access term time in package java,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'DefaultReads.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of java.
[error]       (jsObj \ "items").asOpt[JsArray] match {
```

Comment: I guess having the code raising the error would help.

Comment: `java.time` is a new package in jdk8. Maybe trying to build jdk8 dependent code with jdk7? Message looks like it comes from a macro

Comment: Did you `clean` after migrating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is play-cache dependency. I shouldn't use the latest one. After I use the one matched with Play version, it works.

"com.typesafe.play" % "play-cache_2.11" % "2.3.8"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @richard-close, the issue was caused in my case by having a jdk7 used by sbt.

You can check that with

```
sbt
> eval System.getProperty("java.version")
[info] ans: String = 1.7.0_80
> eval System.getProperty("java.home")
[info] ans: String = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
```